# How to set Flutter Text line space?

Tags: flutter

I had developing app using Android, now I use Flutter, but I want to find the property of Text that is same to `android:includeFontPadding` and `android:lineSpacingExtra`?

Answer (score 196):

It looks like you looking for the `height` property of the `TextStyle` class.
Here is an example:

```
Text(
  "Some lines of text",
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14.0,
    height: 1.5 //You can set your custom height here
  )
)
```

Comment: It work, but I find the first line also has space on the top,  and flutter now has the property the same to  "android:includeFontPadding"

Comment: @andrew have you found a way to remove this "font padding" ?

Answer (score 76):

There are 2 properties you can set

```dart
Text("Hello World", style: TextStyle(
  height: 1.2 // the height between text, default is null
  letterSpacing: 1.0 // the white space between letter, default is 0.0
));
```

Comment: now (Flutter 1.9.1), `height: null` and `height: 1.0` are not same behavior. Default is `height: null` not `height: 1.0`.

Comment: @Terry any idea about character spacing?

Comment: @Soumen that's letterSpacing

Comment: @Mariano Zorrilla yes, I wanted character spacing too. any idea?

Comment: You could check the text style constructors. There are letterSpacing and wordSpacing
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html

There is also RichText class that gives texts multiple styles

Comment: @YuyaMatsuo you are right, and the actual `height` depends on the text's `fontFamily`. For OpenSans and Lato, it seems like it is 120% (equivalent to `height: 1.2` in Flutter). More details in [this Flutter github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29479)

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code:

```
Text(
  "Your text",
  style: TextStyle(height: 1.5),
),
```